# Is there a standard terminology for expressing percentages of variations when computed in 2 different ways?

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I have a bunch of measurements, say 
.71 
.75 
.70 
.79
of a certain quantity.
The range of these measurements is .79-.71 = .08

The percentage of variation can be expressed in 2 ways: (1) range/min_value or (2) range/max_value. For (1) the answer is .08/.71 = .11 or 11%. For (2) the answer is .08/.79 = .10 or 10%.

Both of these answers are correct, but they express slightly different things. So my question is: is there some standard terminology to distinguish between these two percentages, or do I have to explicitly indicate that 11% is the variation with respect to the minimun measurement and 10% is the variation with respect to the maximum measurement?

Comment: Variation can be measured in many more ways than two. FWIW I have never encountered range as % of minimum and as % of maximum, which is not to say that my view isn't myopic or that they might fit some practical purpose. I certainly urge explaining which one you use. As I've never encountered either I don't know any names. The urge to summarize with single measures is usually to be resisted; If the data really were as you say I would want to see all the values rather than any reduction.

Comment: My motivation for range as % of minimum and as % of maximum was to generalize the familiar concept of price increases and price decreases to sets of numbers. For example if the original price of a book is 100 dollars and it's put on sale for 80 dollars, then there is a price decrease of 20%. Whereas if the original price was 80 dollars and the publisher raised the price to 100 dollars, then there is a price increase of 25%. In these cases we don't have to explicitly mention % of maximum or % of minimum since they are already implied by the words increase and decrease.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the [coefficient of variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation) (CV)?

$CV=\frac{s}{\bar{x}}$

Where $s$ is the standard deviation and $\bar{x}$ is the mean. CV can be expressed as a percent.